# Homology groups are finite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am quoting a passage of my notes that I don't understand:

> We want show that the homology groups (over a field $F$) of a closed orientable connected $m$-manifold $M$ are finite dimensional. Suppose $H_i(M,F)\cong \oplus^{\infty}F$. Then by Poincaré duality $H^{m-i}(M,F)\cong \oplus^{\infty}F$ and by the Universal Coefficient Theorem this means that $H_{m-i}(M,F)$ is a vector space whose linear dual is $\oplus^{\infty}F$. **But this is impossible.**

Why should that be impossible? There are vector spaces with infinite-dimensional duals, namely infinite-dimensional vector spaces…

Comment: $\bigoplus^\infty F$ is not the (algebraic) dual of any $F$-vectorspace.  (*Recall*: If $\dim_F V$ is not finite, then the algebraic dual of $V$ has dimension $>\aleph_0$ by diagonalization argument.)

Comment: @user10354138 I know, but the proof seems still wrong to me. We want to prove that no homology group can be infinite-dimensional. We only show that no homology group can have *countably infinite* dimension. The notation $\oplus^{\infty}F$ is imprecise and therefore misleading: We don't assume that this is a countably infinite sum. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, that is very misleading.  Maybe the author meant you get a decreasing sequence of cardinality by considering preduals with this argument?  Anyway, I agree the proof is very suspect depending on which statement of PD and UCT is proved.

Comment: The first issue with this "proof" is in the 2nd sentence, about $\bigoplus^\infty F$: It suggests a countable direct sum without any justification. Secondly, in the proof of PD it is likely that finite dimensionality is already established. But without knowing the details of what else is in your notes, it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 0):

To make a different argument: since $M$ is compact, the homology can be calculated as the simplicial homology of a finite simplicial complex, so everything is happening in a finite-dimensional vector space. (I guess I'm assuming that the manifold is smooth or piecewise linear.)

Comment: Which finite simplicial complex do you mean? Are you assuming the existence of a finite open good cover?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that a compact manifold has a triangulation. I guess that is only true for $m \le 3$, or if the manifold is smooth.

Comment: Topological manifolds admit triangulations only in dimension at most 3, in all higher dimensions there are counter examples (Freedman in 4d and Manolescu in higher dimensions).

Comment: Kirby proved that a compact topological manifold has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex, meaning its homology is finite dimensional.  Having a triangulation is stronger than having the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex so this does not contradict the above comment.

Comment: @AlgTop1854: Yes, or West or Chapman; but in the context of the question, this is a huge overkill. OP is just learning basics of algebraic topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan agree, so a comment in response to others and not intended to be best answer in the context of the query.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this really should have been a comment rather than an answer.